# Problems installing Nerdtree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macvim, nerdtree, pathogen

According to the nerdtree install directions, I needed to install pathogen.vim to install nerdtree.  To install pathogen.vim, I followed the pathogen install instructions, and I did this:

```
~$ mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload ~/.vim/bundle; \
> curl -so ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim \
> <link to github>
```

That created pathogen.vim here:

```
~/.vim/autoload$ ls

pathogen.vim  … … …
```

Then I followed the pathogen install instruction:

```
Add this to your vimrc:

call pathogen#infect()
```

==

```
~$ cat .vimrc
…
…
"For pathogen(a vim installer):
call pathogen#infect()
```

Then following the nerdtree install instructions:

```
pathogen.vim is the recommended way to install nerdtree.

cd ~/.vim/bundle
git clone <link to github>

Then reload vim, run :helptags, and check out :help NERD_tree.txt.
```

I tried to install nerdtree like this:

```
~/.vim/bundle$ git clone <link to github>
Cloning into 'nerdtree'...
remote: Counting objects: 2426, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (801/801), done.
remote: Total 2426 (delta 1091), reused 2354 (delta 1025)
Receiving objects: 100% (2426/2426), 912.52 KiB | 573 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1091/1091), done.
$
```

Which produced:

```
~/.vim$ cd bundle
~/.vim/bundle$ ls
nerdtree
```

But I can't get nerdtree to work.  When I try this:

```
~$ cd rails_projects/demo_app22/
~/rails_projects/demo_app22$ mvim .
~/rails_projects/demo_app22$
```

...and then this:

```
:NERDtree
```

I get the error:

```
E492: Not an editor command: NERDtree
```

And when I try :helptags, I get the error:

```
E472: Argument required
```

Comment: Could you post your whole .vimrc as a gist? Also, do you have the same problem when opening plain vim from the command line?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I deleted .vim/bundle and .vim/autoload/pathogen.vim and started over, and after reinstalling pathogen and nerdtree, it still wouldn't work.  Then I found out what I was doing wrong: :N-E-R-D-T-r-e-e <--> :NERDtree.  Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I missed that, lower case 't'.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this script to deck out Vim for Rails: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567